# AWS ECS: ENV vars out of Task Definition JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, gitlab, devops, amazon-ecs

I'm mounting a gitlab ci script to deploy my multi-container app at Amazon ECS and in the upgrade service part i've to use a json for the task definition with all my containers definitions (image, name, memory, ...).

I need to use environment variables (database password, emails, ...) but i don't want to put in this json file (it will be store at gitlab repository), so what's the best solution for store this variables out of the repository?

AWS recommends to store at S3 volume (https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/security/how-to-manage-secrets-for-amazon-ec2-container-service-based-applications-by-using-amazon-s3-and-docker/) but i don't know if there is a better option.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right to store the cloudformation template in `git`, since it's something that will change and you need to keep track of those changes. But secrets of course have no place in source control! My preferred option in this case is to keep the cloudformation template with the code under source control, and store the secrets in a secure location, like S3 or a private database.

In this situation, you can have the CI system pull the code from your GitLab repository to build the application and run the tests, and then pull the configuration from the chosen location in order to get ready for the deployment.

If you store the secrets in a file in S3, for example, you use a scripts that reads those values and substitutes them in the correct fields in the json (or yaml) file for the task definition. That way you keep the code completely separate from the configuration, and you can manage them independently.